# Proof that Clarke generalized directional derivative is upper continuous

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, variational-inequalities

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space, $z, x, v \in X$. If $f: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous regarding its first argument and locally Lipschitz regarding its second argument. $\{z_i\}, \{x_i\}$ and $\{v_i\}$ are arbitrary sequences converging to $z, x$ and $v$, respectively.

**I wonder** if generalized directional derivative  $f^{0}(z, x; v)$ (in [Clarke sense](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Clarke_generalized_derivative)) satisfies the following inequality:
$$
f^{0}(z, x ; v) \geqslant \limsup _{i \rightarrow \infty} f^{0}\left(z_{i}, x_{i} ; v_{i}\right)
$$

**And I also want to know** how to prove it if the inequality holds.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: [Crossposted on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4398464/39599).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$The answer is no.

Indeed, apparently, in your post the Clarke derivative is meant with respect to the second argument of $f$:
$$f^0(z,x;v):=\limsup_{\substack{y\to x\\ t\downarrow0}}
\frac{f(z,y+tv)-f(z,y)}t.$$

Let now $X:=\R$ and
$$f(z,x):=xe^{-x/|z|}\,1(z\ne0,x>0)$$
for real $z,x$ -- that is, $f(z,x)=xe^{-x/|z|}$ if $z\ne0$ and $x>0$, and $f(z,x)=0$ otherwise. Then $f(z,x)$ is continuous in $z$ and $1$-Lipschitz in $x$.

However, $f^0(0,0;1)=1(z\ne0)$, so that $f^0(z,x;v)$ is not upper-semicontinuous at $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have understood your example. In fact, I want to derive the inequality, i.e. upper-semicontinuous for further using. I wonder if I could make some restrictions on these conditions listed above so that I could derive this inequality. Thanks!

Comment: That would be a different question, which should be posted separately -- just make sure that your modified question is not mistaken for a duplicate. Also, please remove the cross-post from MSE. As for the question actually posted on this page, it has been fully answered. So, let us have a closure here: https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers and https://mathoverflow.net/help/accepted-answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have accepted your answer, and I have posted a new question here: [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417691/the-conditions-used-to-prove-upper-semicontinuous-of-generalized-directional-der). If you have any ideas, please feel free to answer the question in this link.