# The conditions used to prove upper semicontinuous of generalized directional derivative (in Clarke sense)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, variational-inequalities

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space, $z, x, v \in X$. $\{z_i\}, \{x_i\}$ and $\{v_i\}$ are arbitrary sequences converging to $z, x$ and $v$, respectively.

**I would like to know** under which **conditions of the function $f: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$**, generalized directional derivative  $f^{0}(z, x; v)$ (in [Clarke sense](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Clarke_generalized_derivative)) satisfy the following inequality:
$$
f^{0}(z, x ; v) \geqslant \limsup _{i \rightarrow \infty} f^{0}\left(z_{i}, x_{i} ; v_{i}\right)
$$

**Conditions of the function $f$ I can accept:** For this $f$, I need it is locally Lipschitz regarding its second argument at least. Regarding its first argument, I want the function to have properties like Lipschitz continuous or something similar to continuous.

**And I also want to know** how to prove it if there are these conditions.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: To avoid the tautological answer (the desired conclusion holds whenever it holds), I think you need to specify the terms (acceptable to you) in which the sufficient conditions are to be expressed.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your meaning, and I try to re-edit this question. In this question, I hope to add some restrictions on $f$ to prove the upper semicontinuous. However, I don't know how to figure out this question now. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: One could add the restriction "the inequality in question holds". With this restriction, the inequality in question will of course hold. But, most likely, you will find this additional restriction unacceptable. So, then you need to specify what kind(s) of restrictions, in what terms, will be acceptable to you. Any question on MathOverflow should be stated so that it be clear what will constitute an answer and what will not.  Your question is not stated that way, it is too open-ended.

Comment: Thanks for your explaining. I have re-edited this question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$The conditions that you can accept are not enough for the conclusion that you desire.

Indeed, as in the [previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417683/36721), let $X:=\R$ and
$$f(z,x):=xe^{-x/|z|}\,1(z\ne0,x>0)$$
for real $z,x$ -- that is, $f(z,x)=xe^{-x/|z|}$ if $z\ne0$ and $x>0$, and $f(z,x)=0$ otherwise. Then $f(z,x)$ is $C$-Lipschitz in $z$ (with $C:=(2/e)^2$) and $1$-Lipschitz in $x$.

However, $f^0(0,0;1)=1(z\ne0)$, so that $f^0(z,x;v)$ is not upper-semicontinuous at $(0,0,1)$.

---

If we modify the above example a bit, as follows:
$$f(z,x):=xe^{-|x|/|z|}\,1(z\ne0)$$
for real $z$ and $x$, then we will see that $f(z,x)$ is, not only $C$-Lipschitz in $z$ and $1$-Lipschitz in $x$, but also continuously differentiable in $z$ and in $x$, and yet still with $f^0(0,0;1)=1(z\ne0)$, so that $f^0(z,x;v)$ is not upper-semicontinuous at $(0,0,1)$.

---

On the other hand, the conclusion you desire will obviously hold if $f(z,x)$ has a partial derivative in $x$ which is continuous in $(z,x)$.

Comment: Well, for this $f$, I need it is locally Lipschitz regarding its second argument because in Clarke's book, for $g^{0}(x; v)$, $g(x)$ is Lipschitz. For the first argument of $f$, do you think there are any restriction to make the conclusion hold. I mean if I can strengthen the conditions to make the conclusion hold. If you have any ideas or suggestions, please comment here. Thanks.

Comment: I think the focus of this question is making restriction on the first argument of $f(z, x)$ if I want to have this conclusion. I am not sure if I am in the right way.

Comment: (i) Since in the above examples $f(z,x)$ is Lipschitz in $x$, it is trivially locally Lipschitz in $x$. So, there is no problem with the local Lipschitz condition. (ii) I have now added a trivial sufficient condition, that $f(z,x)$ have a partial derivative in $x$ which is continuous in $(z,x)$. (iii) At least intuitively, it is clear that no conditions on the behavior of $f(x,y)$ **separately** with respect to $z$ and with respect to $x$ will be enough to get your desired semi-continuity **jointly** in $(z,x)$.

Comment: Previous comment continued: I have now added a modified example, with $f(z,x)$, not only $C$-Lipschitz in $z$ and $1$-Lipschitz in $x$, but also continuously differentiable in $z$ and in $x$. (iv) You may be better off if you disclose more about your ultimate goal here. At this point, the question and answer are ready for closure.

Comment: Okay, I have understood your ideas, and I will think about it. If I have further questions, I will post its link here. Thanks a lot for your support.